# Tokenbased signon to Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a custom built web-application (App-Cust) that needs to integrate / implement a single signon to an Oracle APEX 5 application (App-Apex).

An user is logged in as userA in the custom application ang should be signed in to the APEX application as userAA based on thrust between the two applications.

Ie. 
userA clicks a button/link in App-Cust taking him to App-Apex.
App-Cust acquires some kind og token from App-Apex for userAA 
App-Cust returns the token with an redirect URL to App-Apex
The userA is redirected to App-Apex and logged in as userAA

I have little knowledge of Oracle APEX.

Is there an easy/preferred way to do this in APEX?

Comment: You should use a custom authentication scheme and either transfer generated Tokens from one DB to the other or preferably use something like PGP and Certificates (asynchronous Encryption). Another Idea would be to use the same Single Sign on for both (Google Sign-On for example) Since Apex 18.1 supports that natively.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the answer here http://www.oracle-and-apex.com/authenticate-apex-via-token/
this will enable the token based authentication. Else you can use the same custom authentication and share it between the applications, call the same auth function in application B same as Application A and provide login page (url) for Application B as login page for application A